# In React JS, How to display the data in this loop in user interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using React JS. From the below code I can see the data from this loop in my console, I want to display the data to UI. How can I do that?

This is the sample data from an api

```
{
  "note": "",
  "notification": "",
  "Books": [
    {
      "bookID": 65342,
      "img": "https://unsplash.com/photos/AqX_786_G0g",
      "year": 2018,
      "bookTitle": "Story Time",
      "LibraryInfo": {
        "Status": Out,
        "returnDate":7 Jan        
      }
    },
```

```
for(const key of Object.keys(details)) {
    console.log("Key",key);
      }
 for(const value of Object.values(details)) {
        console.log("Values",value);
     
          }
for(const entry of Object.entries(details)) {
            console.log("Entries", entry);
    }
```

Comment: What did you tried? Show us your code where you actually implement something.

Comment: Also the data you showed us seems to be not complete nor valid.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
{
  keys.map(key => (
    <p> {key} </p>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to loop through a Javascript Object you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), this function will return an Array of the keys of your Object, as for your dataset you will have an array like that

```
["note", "notification", "Books", ...]
```

As soon as you have this Array you could use a normal loop or some Array utility methods like map to access to the values via brackets notation.

```
const keys = Object.keys(myObj);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(myObj[i]); // You print the associated with that key
}
// An alternative
keys.map(data => console.log(myObj[data]));
```

If you want to print that in React map is a good solution for your problem, you could do something like

```
{keys.map((data, i) => <p key={data + i}>{myObj[data]}</p>)}
```